# OpenCV video only show a single frame instead of continuous frame

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

When I try to export the following video, it only shows a single frame for 12 seconds, I want to show the original video but it only shows one single frame

Below are the code attached:

````
ret, frame = day_video.read()
height, width = frame.shape[:2]

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (width,height))

while day_video.isOpened():
  ret, frame = day_video.read()
  if not ret:
    out.release()
    break

  new_output = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
  out.write(new_output)

out.release()```
````

The output I get which is only same frame for 12 seconds.
[![Sample output][1]][1]

The code i use to enhance the original artwork

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/Shareddrives/Computer Vision/Assignment 2/Q1_day_video.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 0, 1)
    sobel_all = cv2.add(sobelx, sobely)

    (ret_otsu,thresh_otsu) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    print(ret_otsu)
    
    # add the threshold effect with sobel filter
    result = cv2.add(sobel_all, thresh_otsu)
    cv2_imshow(result)
    break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The following changes I have made, but It just keep infinite loading

````
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/Shareddrives/Computer Vision/Assignment 2/Q1_day_video.avi')
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, _ = frame.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (width,height))   

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0)
  sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 0, 1)
  sobel_all = cv2.add(sobelx, sobely)
  (ret_otsu,thresh_otsu) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# add the threshold effect with sobel filter 
  result = cv2.add(sobel_all, thresh_otsu)
  new_output = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
  new2_output = new2_output + new_output

if not ret:
  out.release()
  break

out.write(new3_output)
        
cap.release()```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0wCx.png
````

Comment: You are breaking the loop after the first video frame... Replace the `break` after `cv2_imshow(result)` with `if not ret:` `break`. Where is the implementation of `cv2_imshow`? It should be something like `cv2.imshow('result', result)` `cv2.waitKey(1)`

Comment: ```while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0)
  sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 0, 1)
  sobel_all = cv2.add(sobelx, sobely)
  (ret_otsu,thresh_otsu) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  result = cv2.add(sobel_all, thresh_otsu)
  new_output = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
  new2_output = new2_output + new_output

if not ret:
  out.release()
  break


out.write(new3_output)
        
cap.release()```

it just keeps infinite loading, have I made a mistake on specific part?

Comment: @Rotem, cv_imshow is colabs drop-in replacement (cant use opencv's gui there)

Answer (score 0):

Your latest code block is infinite loading because your break statement is indented incorrectly - it needs to be inside the while loop. Also, you are only applying the sobel filter to the first frame and always writing that frame to the final video. You need to put the logical statements in the order in which you want them to be executed.

Your code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/Shareddrives/Computer Vision/Assignment 2/Q1_day_video.avi')
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, _ = frame.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (width,height))   

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0)
  sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 0, 1)
  sobel_all = cv2.add(sobelx, sobely)
  (ret_otsu,thresh_otsu) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# add the threshold effect with sobel filter 
  result = cv2.add(sobel_all, thresh_otsu)
  new_output = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
  new2_output = new2_output + new_output

if not ret:
  out.release()
  break

out.write(new3_output)
        
cap.release()
```

Correct code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/Shareddrives/Computer Vision/Assignment 2/Q1_day_video.avi')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (width,height))   

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if not ret:
    out.release()
    break
  height, width, _ = frame.shape
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0)
  sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_8U, 0, 1)
  sobel_all = cv2.add(sobelx, sobely)
  (ret_otsu,thresh_otsu) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  # add the threshold effect with sobel filter 
  result = cv2.add(sobel_all, thresh_otsu)
  new_output = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
  new2_output = new2_output + new_output
  out.write(new2_output)
        
cap.release()
```